# VBA handle missing references

Tags: excel, vba, listview, listbox

Is there a way to disable a user form if it contains controls that are not compatible with the current Excel version?

I'm trying to upgrade listBox controls to listView, but if I use a listView control and send the file to a colleague that has Office 365 64bit or Office 2013 they will get an error as soon as they open the file, even if the form is not called("Could not load an object because it's not available on this machine")

I have a piece of code that checks for incompatible versions, but I need to code to disable forms, or prevent the error from displaying for the users:

```
    'COMPARE 32 vs 64bit version
    #If VBA7 Then
        'Debug.Print "Code is running in the new VBA7 editor"
        #If Win64 Then
            isBitOk = False
        #Else
            isBitOk = True
        #End If
    #Else
        isBitOk = False
    #End If
```

Comment: Application.Operatingsystem returns the OS name as string.

Comment: OP needs to be told how to construct a form dynamically in VBA and place controls on it. I don't know how to do such a thing but I understand it's possible.

Comment: @Joshua Thank you for the idea, I know how to build a form, thanks for the idea. The problem is you can build a form with basic functionality, i'm not sure you can add macro functionality like sorting columns for an auto created form, it has some limitations.